# Security Warning: The negotiated TLS 1.0 is an insecure protocol and is supported for backward compatibility only. ERROR accessing API IN Blazor WASM

Tags: blazor, webassembly

I am trying to run a Blazor WASM project that accesses a local CRUD API. I get the error once I run the component that accesses the API inside the Package Manager Console >>Dotnet watch run command. The developer console message says:

> "Failed to load resource: 5000/api/CompanyInfo/1:1 the server responded with a status of 404 ()" I am using a Windows 10 machine.

Someone please assist: error below.

> Security Warning: The negotiated TLS 1.0 is an insecure protocol and is supported for backward compatibility only. The recommended protocol version is TLS 1.2 and later

Comment: As far as I can see, there are some Microsoft's Engineering Improvements to eliminate TLS 1.0 dependencies. You can have as reference the following oficial documentation: [Solving the TLS 1.0 Problem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/engineering/solving-tls1-problem) And focus on this section: [Finding and fixing TLS 1.0 dependencies in code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/engineering/solving-tls1-problem#finding-and-fixing-tls-1.0-dependencies-in-code) I hope this information is useful for you. Regards.

Comment: Why is that API using TLS1.0? The error is clear - TLS1.2 is *very* weak and considered insecure. Almost all major services (including cloud services) require TLS1.2 at least, for at least 5 years. PCI-DSS compliance (which you need to be able to use any form of payment) requires TLS1.2 as well.

Comment: Thank you guys. This error had nothing to do with my code but in my Windows 10, TLS1.0 was enabled. So the I had to implement the solution provided on the link by https://stackoverflow.com/users/16922044/nestor-daniel-ortega-perez: